# Update a graphic color using a button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, colors, graphic

I am trying to update the colors of some elipses and lines that are drawn when the frame is constructed. 
I then want to change the color using a button on the frame.

```
package animation.test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GraphDisplayTest extends JFrame {

static GraphDisplayTest gui;

private JButton changeColorBtn = new JButton("Change Color");
private Graphics2D g2;
private Ellipse2D e1;
private Ellipse2D e2;
private Ellipse2D e3;
private Ellipse2D e4;
int x = 50, y = 50, w = 20, h = 20;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    gui = new GraphDisplayTest();
    gui.launch();

}

public void launch(){
    gui.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    gui.add(changeColorBtn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    changeColorBtn.addActionListener(new ChangeColor());

    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setTitle("Graph Display Example");
    gui.setSize(350, 400);
    gui.setVisible(true);
}

public class ChangeColor implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    //HERE IS THE PROBLEM - the colors are not being reset
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fill(e1);
        g2.drawLine(x+10, y+10, x+210, y+10);
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
}


public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.drawLine(x+10, y+10, x+210, y+10);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.drawLine(x+210, y+10, x+210, y+210);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.drawLine(x+10, y+210, x+210, y+210);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.drawLine(x+10, y+10, x+10, y+210);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    e1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
    g2.fill(e1);
    e2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(x+200, y, w, h);
    g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
    g2.fill(e2);
    e3 = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y+200, w, h);
    g2.setPaint(Color.GREEN);
    g2.fill(e3);
    e4 = new Ellipse2D.Double(x+200, y+200, w, h);
    g2.setPaint(Color.YELLOW);
    g2.fill(e4);

}


}
```

I have commened where i have no idea what to do! Can anyone help?!?!

Many thanks in advance
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store the value of Graphics object (in this case: g2).

Create a new attribute to store the color of e1:

```
Color c = Color.BLUE;
```

Delete all code in `actionPerformed(...)` and set the value of c to the new color.  Then, call `repaint()`.

```
c = Color.BLACK;
repaint();
```

In `paint(...)`, change the lines:

```
g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
g2.fill(e1);
```

to:

```
g2.setPaint(c);
g2.fill(e1);
```

Answer (score 2):

each time paint is called you overwrite the old graphics which has the color information

it's better add a field color initialized to `Color.BLACK` which you use inside paint and update that inside the actionPerformed of the listener

on another note saving the graphics and using it outside the paint "event" is not recommended

Answer (score 1):

The graphics-object is only making real changes, in the paint-method. So saving the Graphics-object (in your case g2) is of no use. Instead put the color in a variable and change the color the time the button is pressed. Use in the paint-method the color-variable, so it will repaint with the new color the next time paint is called.

Maybe you also need to call `repaint()`. That commands the awt-thread to make a new call to paint.

Answer (score 1):

The Graphics object you use in the ActionListener is already on the screen. Drawing on it won't work. What you have to do is to hold a field in which you keep track of the color (*). And when the action listener runs, set the color to whatever you want and then call `repaint()`. It's a method of the JFrame that will make the window repaint, which will call the `paint(Graphics g)` you wrote. Inside that method, check for the color you hold (the same as I marked by the asterisk *). Depending on the color, set the color of the Graphics object and then paint.